# Импорт функции

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, c++, dll

У меня есть библиотека с такой функцией

```
#define THIS_EXPORT  __declspec (dllexport)

THIS_EXPORT void NET_NetConnect(char* Host,int PortUDP,unsigned int PortTCP,void * WorldData);
```

Функция находится в классе в разделе public. Я хочу импортировать эту функцию, но ничего не выходит. Вот как я делаю

```
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hMyDll;
    if ((hMyDll = LoadLibrary("Client.dll")) == NULL) {
        printf("Errorn");
    } else {
        printf("Dll loaded! n");
    }

    typedef void (WINAPI * NET_NetConnect) (char *Host, int PortUDP, unsigned int PortTCP, void *WorldData);
    NET_NetConnect MyConnectTest;

    //hMyDll=LoadLibrary("Client.dll");
    MyConnectTest = (NET_NetConnect) GetProcAddress(hMyDll, "NET_NetConnect");

    (MyConnectTest) ("127.0.0.1", 50001, 50005, &CWorld);

    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, что не так. Я декомпилировал DLL библиотеку и увидел, что функции экспортируются... но вызвать их не могу... просто приложение падает на последней строчке. Может надо в def файл записать функцию или я тут какую-то мелочь упустил, не так сделал?

Comment: GetProcAddress(hMyDll,"NET_NetConnect") что возвращает ? Проверять надо.

Comment: Я не понимаю, как вызывать void процедуру... в примерах в интернете одни процедуры с int попадаются =(

Comment: Я уже даже в def файл запихал функцию...НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ =(
Результат GetProcAdress == 0xcccccccc . он ее кажись не находит просто

Comment: Попробуйте AfxLoadLibrary [отсюда](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d5fzd0ek.aspx)

    Be sure to use AfxLoadLibrary and AfxFreeLibrary (instead of the Win32 functions LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary) if your application uses multiple threads and if it dynamically loads an extension DLL. Using AfxLoadLibrary and AfxFreeLibrary insures that the startup and shutdown code that executes when the extension DLL is loaded and unloaded does not corrupt the global MFC state.

Answer (score 3):

- Ваша функция в хедере объявлена как `THIS_EXPORT void NET_NetConnect(...)`, что идеологически соответствует `void Foo(...)`
- Когда вы импортируете функцию, то вы объявляете ее как `typedef void (WINAPI * NET_NetConnect) (...)`, что соответствует `void * Foo(...)`.
- *Понятно, что несоответствие сигнатур в таком случае ведет к `runtime` ошибке*

Comment: Спасибо,вопрос снят

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void (__stdcall *MYPROC1)(char* Host,int PortUDP,unsigned int PortTCP,void * WorldData);

HMODULE hLib = LoadLibraryA("Client.dll");
if (hLib)
{
    MYPROC1 NET_NetConnect= (MYPROC1)GetProcAddress(hLib, "NET_NetConnect");
    if (NET_NetConnect)
    {
       NET_NetConnect("127.0.0.1", 50001, 50005, &CWorld);
    }
}
```

И в def файле библиотеки прописать

```
LIBRARY Client
EXPORTS
    NET_NetConnect
```